# Horizontally center <span> inside <a>

Tags: css, html, text-align

I want to horizontally center a span inside an a-tag. The problem is that I can't set the height nor the width of the span. My markups is as follows:

```
<div class="footer">
     <a href="#">
          <span>Show/Hide</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.footer {position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%;}
.footer a {display:block; background:orange; text-align:center;}
.footer a span {background:#FFF; font-size:12px; width:100px;}
```

I've tried everything, but think I need some sort of float somewhere, but don't know. Help are gladly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Looks centered to me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tqwRp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set dimensions of `display: inline` elements.

You can either have both the a and the span have `display: block`, if you want to explicitly set its width:

```
.footer {position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%;}
.footer a {display:block; background:orange;} /* no need to center text, here */
.footer a span {
  display: block; /* give it a box layout */
  margin: 0px auto; /* center it horizontally */
  width:100px; /* give it explicit absolute size */
  text-align: center; /* you might center the content here, though */
  background:#FFF; font-size:12px;}
```

or just use `text-align: center` as you are already doing:

```
.footer {position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%;}
.footer a {display:block; background:orange; text-align:center;}
.footer a span {background:#FFF; font-size:12px;
  padding: 0px 30px;} /* if you only want some padding, and not a fixed width
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

.footer a span {background:#FFF; font-size:12px; width:50%; display:block; margin: 0 auto;}

The 'inner span' needs a width less than the 'outer' div (or footer) along with a margin: 0 setting to auto align.

Answer (score -4):

You can do

```
<center> </center>
```

So like this,

```
<div class="footer">
<center>
 <a href="#">
      <span>Show/Hide</span>
 </a>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element was deprecated back around the Clinton administration.

Comment: Also the `a` tag is set to `display:block` which means it'll be 100% width unless otherwise specified.